# NumberFormatException line 80

Tags: java

I do not understand why I am getting `sorting.java:80: cannot find symbol` ... `catch (NumberFormatExecption ex) {` is pointing at the "N"

```
while(true) {
     System.out.println("(1) Bubble Sort (2) Selection Sort (3) Insertion Sort");
     System.out.print("From the choices above, which selection sort would you like to choose: ");
     selectionSort = input.readLine();

     try {
        sortRunner = Integer.parseInt(selectionSort);

        if(sortRunner == 1) {
           // run bubble sort
           // print order
           break;
        }
        else if (sortRunner == 2) {
           // run Selection sort
           //print order
           break;
        }
        else if(sortRunner == 3) {
           // run selection sort
           // print order
           break;
        }
     }
     catch (NumberFormatExecption ex) {
        System.err.println("You need to enter a valid input when selection your selection sort. Try again.");
     }      
  }
```

Comment: `NumberFormatException` (typo?).

Comment: Thanks.. I thought I looked at the spelling several times.

Comment: Your `try` block covers a lot of code when it really only needs to cover the `Integer.parseInt(selectionSort);` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spelling and case count:

*NumberFormatExecption  != NumberFormatException*